# clicking dropdown menubar item shows blank page in php

Tags: php

I've have a menubar item with the name `Activity` which on hover prints `Items` and `Lists`. The code belonging to the menubar item `Activity` is shown below:

```
<li>
    <section>
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <a href="index.php?location=actionsMenu:index"><?=$ab_string['activity']; ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="sm">
            <div class="span">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?location=actionsMenu:index"><?=$ab_string['items'];?></a></li>   // Line A for dropddown Items 
                    <li><a href="index.php?location=actionsMenu:lists"><?=$ab_string['lists'];?></a></li>   // Line B for dropdown Lists
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</li>
```

On doing hover to `Activity` menubar item, it shows dropdown `Items` and `Lists`. On clicking dropdown `Items`, I am seeing the blank page.

**Problem Statement:** I am wondering what changes I need to make at Line A so that it doesn't show blank page on clicking `Items`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you handle the GET var "location" in your index.php? Something is breaking in index.php, likely a "fatal error" and with error reporting suppressed, that will lead to a completely blank page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.php?location=actionsMenu:index&data=<?=$ab_string['items'];?>"><?=$ab_string['items'];?></a>
<a href="index.php?location=actionsMenu:lists&data=<?=$ab_string['lists'];?>"><?=$ab_string['lists'];?></a>
```

Put the variable to the href, and using `$_GET['data']` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Still it prints blank page.

Comment: Means you got an issue does not related open a new tab or existing tab ? If the issues related to the display logic, please revise the questions and attach the structure of `$ab_string`, ps, you can using `print_r($ab_string)` to dump the structure.